# Problems with search query using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i just want a direct answer and explanation why my prior query works but the latter does not..

here is the query that works just fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productslist WHERE brand LIKE ?";
```

and this doesn't work at all and just returns an error:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM productslist WHERE brand LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';
```

can someone please explain me why the latter query doesn;t work at all?

thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the value of `$search_string` ? Are you using prepared statements ?

Comment: any error? what value is assigned to search_string variable?

Comment: Are you aware of sql injection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Try to change quotas you use like this: $sql = "SELECT * FROM productslist WHERE brand LIKE '%"  .$search_string.  "%'  "; Sometimes quotas cause errors. In alternative you can always echo your query, copy it and execute directly in db and see if you have any db error.

Comment: My guess is that `$search_string` contains a quote symbol.

Comment: @Nick i think your suggestion about testing a query is a good way of testing if a query can be successfully executed..

Comment: which api did you use to connect with here and query? mysql_? mysqli_? PDO? other?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this with PDO (Edit: Including PDO connection string since he didn't specify if he was using PDO) -

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:hostname=$your_server;dbname=$database_name, $username, $password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM productslist WHERE brand LIKE :search";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(":search", "%$search_string%");
$query->execute();

$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the query with a table on my own DB. worked fine... I used a constant

Try mysqli_real_escape_string:

```
$search_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $search_string);
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM productslist WHERE brand LIKE "%'. $search_string  .'%"';
```

Comment: It's better and 100% safe to user prepared statements instead of `escape`